# Can't load python3 packages (even with virtualenv)

Tags: python, module, pip, virtualenv

Im installing packages for my python 3.8 inside WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. The installations goes smoothly using pip3 install, but vscode doesn't recognize the modules.

I tried creating a virtual environment, installing the libraries there, and selecting the interpreter for this virtual env inside vscode, but it doesnt work. Any tips on how can i fix those?

Here are some command outputs:

```
➜  ~  pip -V
pip 21.2.2 from /home/renatochaz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

➜  ~ python3 -V
Python 3.8.10

➜  ~ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

➜  ~ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

➜  ~ pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
attrs==19.3.0
Automat==0.8.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloud-init==21.2
colorama==0.4.3
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
cupshelpers==1.0
dbus-python==1.2.16
defer==1.0.6
distlib==0.3.2
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
entrypoints==0.3
filelock==3.0.12
httplib2==0.14.0
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
incremental==16.10.1
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonpatch==1.22
jsonpointer==2.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
keyring==18.0.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
lineedit==0.1.6
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
more-itertools==4.2.0
netifaces==0.10.4
numpy==1.21.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==1.3.1
pexpect==4.6.0
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycairo==1.16.2
pycparser==2.20
pycups==1.9.73
Pygments==2.9.0
PyGObject==3.36.0
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyRFC3339==1.1
pyrsistent==0.15.5
pyserial==3.4
python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.5
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3.1
radian==0.5.11
rchitect==0.3.32
requests==2.22.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
service-identity==18.1.0
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.14.0
sos==4.1
ssh-import-id==5.10
systemd-python==234
Twisted==18.9.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools==27.2
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.25.8
virtualenv==20.4.7
wadllib==1.3.3
wcwidth==0.2.5
wget==3.2
zipp==1.0.0
zope.interface==4.7.1
```

Comment: "but vscode doesn't recognize the modules" Does it work when you write code with an ordinary text editor and run it from the command line?

Comment: Could you at least provide a screenshot supporting your question?

Comment: I found that if i open VSCode directly from windows (but still running inside WSL2), it recognizes the modules. But if i open the vscode using code . inside the terminal, it doesn't recognize then. 
This makes no sense to me ._.